# AngularJS ngBind with multiplication and sum

Tags: angularjs, sum, ng-bind

I have four products and i am taking its quantity from user. these products have fixed price and i want to display total amount in last.

This is my Controller

```
application.controller('SaleController', function ($scope) {
 $scope.Spaghetti_price=50;
 $scope.Macaroni_price=100;
 $scope.Noodles_price=40;
 $scope.MegaNoodles_price=70;
}
```

And Here is my view

```
<div>
<input type="number" class="text-input" ng-model="Spaghetti_qty" />
<input type="number" class="text-input" ng-model="Macaroni_qty"  />
<input type="number" class="text-input" ng-model="Noodles_qty" />
<input type="number" class="text-input" ng-model="MegaNoodles_qty"  />
</div>
<div>
Total Amount: 
<input type="number" class="text-input" ng-model="totalAmount" ng-bind="(Spaghetti_qty*Spaghetti_price)+(Macaroni_qty*Macaroni_price)+(Noodles_qty*Noodles_price)+(MegaNoodles_qty*MegaNoodles_price)"/>
</div>
```

But above code is not working i am not getting any updated value in total amount textbox. I want live update in amount textbox as user enters quantity for products.

Is any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Why is your total an `<input>` field? Shouldn't it be, say, a `<div>{{Spaghetti_qty*Spaghetti_price + ...}}</div>`?

Comment: I also want it editable. that's why it is in input field

Comment: What would that do to the calculation? Once user edits, the total is no longer calculated?

Comment: It is not showing updated value in textbox. i want to show it once user add or edit quantity value

Comment: I don't understand what the behavior is when you both want the value to be edited by the user and also calculated. What happens if the user edits the total and then edits the qty - what will the total reflect? The user input or will it recalculate the total?

Comment: Let's assume that user will not edit the qty if he edits total. but question is not what user does. question is how can i get updated total in textbox.

Comment: The question *is* what the behavior is - that is what needs to be modeled with a View Model, and the View will only reflect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start with the behavior and model it. So, a behavior of calculated vs. entered ***is*** very important.

Specifically, let's define a variable that stores the state of whether the "total" is calculated or not.

```
$scope.isTotalCalculated = true; // at first it is calculated
```

We'll also need the variable to hold the total - `$scope.totalAmount` - it would be updated with each change in quantity, unless `$scope.isTotalCalculated === false`.

And we'll need the `updateTotal()` function.

All together, it looks like so:

```
$scope.isTotalCalculated = true;
$scope.totalAmount = 0;
$scope.updateTotal = updateTotal;

updateTotal(); // initial update of total

function updateTotal(){
   if (!$scope.isTotalCalculated) return;
   $scope.totalAmount = $scope.Spaghetti_price * $scope.Spaghetti_qty + ...
}
```

Then you just need to wire it up to the View:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="Spaghetti_qty" ng-change="updateTotal()" />
<input type="number" ng-model="Macaroni_qty"  ng-change="updateTotal()" />
...

<input type="number" ng-model="totalAmount" ng-change="isTotalCalculated = false" />
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/02IwQRX2eplzFYM7qEiI?p=preview)**